# Relation between number of photons and energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, visible-light, photons, luminosity

Please can anyone explain it.

If number of photons are increased will it increase the providing energy.

Suppose, we are sending a limited number of photons each carrying energy. We have a energy detector it receives photons and tell us about their energy. Now if we increase the number of photons will the detector show an increase in energy or will it be constant.

Please clear it to me.

I think there is fixed amount of energy for a given EM wave and by increasing number of photons energy is divided in same ration and in same proportion in all photons so energy remains constant.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things. More photons means a brighter beam. power (Energy/sec) is proportional to the number of photons/sec.

Photons with shorter wavelengths and higher frequencies have more energy. That is a bluer beam has more power.

So $P = nh\nu$ where n is the number of photons/sec.

Comment: ... so you can get the same power from a beam by reducing the wavelength and increasing the number of photons/sec.